# Removing child from CCParallaxNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I am using a `CCParallaxNode` to add some sprites (clouds) with different parallaxRatios and z. When the clouds get out of the screen I want to remove them from the `CCParallaxNode`. But when I do it I receive an error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

This error is thrown in the visit method of the `CCParallaxNode` when it tries to access the its child position:

```
-(void) visit
{
    CGPoint pos = [self absolutePosition_];
    if( ! CGPointEqualToPoint(pos, _lastPosition) ) {
        for (CGPointObject *point in _parallaxArray) {
            float x = -pos.x + pos.x * point.ratio.x + point.offset.x;
            float y = -pos.y + pos.y * point.ratio.y + point.offset.y;
            point.child.position = ccp(x,y); //error is thrown here
        }
        _lastPosition = pos;
    }
    [super visit];
}
```

This is how I am removing the child node:

```
    [_parallax addChild:cloud z:-z parallaxRatio:ccp(1/(CGFloat)z,0) positionOffset:cloud.position];
    CGFloat life = 6;
    [cloud runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[[CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:life],[CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^(){
        [_parallax removeChild:cloud cleanup:YES];
    }]]]];
```

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with the code you have, have you got NSZombieEnabled? It usually help with debugging this sort of issues.

Comment: @lucianomarisi by turning on NSZombieEnabled I get the following error message: [CCSprite retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1265ed110. Any thoughts?